# Modify regex code, only one line

Tags: vb.net, regex

I have this code

```
Dim parts As New List(Of String)(Regex.Split(RichTextBox2.Text, "~\d"))
```

That splits lines in this format into parts:

```
~1Hello~2~3Bye~4~5Morning~6
```

So if I do `MsgBox(parts(5))`, it will show me "Morning".

---

I want to do the exact same thing, but now my line is arranged like this:

```
Hello, Bye, Morning,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `"~\d"` to `", ?"`. The question mark after the space means that the space is optional.

Alternatively, assuming that you are only looking for single words, instead of `Regex.Split` you could use [**`Regex.Matches`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx) with the regular expression `"\w+"`.